# How to prevent that "Action Not Found" and a list of tried URIs is shown using Play?

Tags: playframework

The [Routing in Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting) documentation has been read and multiple code samples have been run including [this one](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-simple-oauth). When one navigates to an unknown URI it returns a list of tried URIs:

[image]

**Expected outcome**

The expectation was that no information would have been returned when one navigates to an unknown URI or is unauthorized or forbidden like in [Apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/httpd.html). No matter what URI one tries, the unauthorized message is always returned and no information regarding tried URIs is shown:

[image]

**Question**

How to prevent that "Action Not Found" and a list of tried URIs is shown using Play?

**Discussion**

It could be possible that some settings are required in the `conf/application.conf` to prevent that a list of tried URIs will be shown, but it is unclear how this could be done.

Comment: That information is only displayed in DEV mode, for debugging purposes. When you're in production mode, it only show the orange parts.

Comment: If you want to customise the page, you can create [a custom error handler](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling) that overrides this behaviour and returns your own view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking this down by point:

> The expectation was that no information would have been returned when one navigates to an unknown URI

When you try to access an unknown resource, you will get back a 404.  In dev mode, you will receive the list of possible paths to help you during development.  In production mode, you get the same page but without "These routes have been tried..." or the routes themselves.

> or is unauthorized or forbidden

Even in dev mode, accessing forbidden or unauthorized resources will result in 403 or 401 responses as required, but you have to have configured this behaviour using something like Deadbolt for authorization and one of several libraries for authentication.

For reference, Play's `play.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler` processes response codes with this code

```
public CompletionStage<Result> onClientError(RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) {
    if (statusCode == 400) {
        return onBadRequest(request, message);
    } else if (statusCode == 403) {
        return onForbidden(request, message);
    } else if (statusCode == 404) {
        return onNotFound(request, message);
    } else if (statusCode >= 400 && statusCode < 500) {
        return onOtherClientError(request, statusCode, message);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("onClientError invoked with non client error status code " + statusCode + ": " + message);
    }
}
```

with the `404` having a special case that depends on the mode.

```
protected CompletionStage<Result> onNotFound(RequestHeader request, String message){
    if (environment.isProd()) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.notFound(views.html.defaultpages.notFound.render(
                request.method(), request.uri())));
    } else {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.notFound(views.html.defaultpages.devNotFound.render(
                request.method(), request.uri(), Some.apply(routes.get())
        )));
    }
}
```